# How can I return text only from Spring servlet?

Tags: ajax, spring, http, servlets, single-page-application

Here's the story, I have a single page application, where I want to call a servlet from an ajax object, and have the text returned from the servlet be displayed on my webpage.

Here's an example of how I could do it:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submittext() {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "submit", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        document.getElementById("myTextField").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>


    <input type="text" name="mytext" />
    <br>
    <button onClick="submittext()">Submit</button>
    <br>        
    <div id="myTextField"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>testdogservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>testdogservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/submit</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**testdogservlet-servlet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="world.hello.mytest" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**MyServlet.java**

```
package world.hello.mytest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MyServlet {


    private String savedText;
    @RequestMapping("/submit")
    public ModelAndView submitText()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("text", "barModelName", "submission successful ModelObject");

    }



}
```

**text.jsp**

```
${barModelName};
```

This solution works fine. You click the submit button, and it changes the div contents to text contained in text.jsp.

The question is, it seems redundant to have an entire page dedicated as just the container for holding this text. Is there a tidier solution for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spring controller can pass in the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletReponse into the mapped methods.

Modify your method to accept these two arguments, and then you can directly modify the HttpServletResponse.

```
@RequestMapping("/submit")
private void submit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{           
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    os.write("submission successful ModelObject".getBytes());
    os.close();
    os.flush();     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping("/submit")
@ResponseBody
public String submitText()
{
    return "submission successful ModelObject";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the return object to something like this:

```
private String savedText;
    @RequestMapping("/submit")
    public String submitText()
    {
        return "submission successful ModelObject";

    }
```

My advice is convert it to JSON object using either @RestController or Jackson JSON converter.

Comment: That's going to give: `HTTP Status 404 - /mytest/WEB-INF/jsp/submission successful ModelObject.jsp`

Comment: Right so your view engine is going to percieve it as ready for rendering. In that case convert it to restfull and it should then eliminate that problem. Generally from personal xp, any non page rendering response i code into restfull manner. Have you considered converting to JSON format?

Comment: Yes, eventually it will be JSON format, but for now I'm just working out how to pass back some text. Check out the answer I gave.

Comment: Yep that is another way, but question then becomes why? That can get rather messy as your code grows. Skip straight to JSON/Restfull method.